# Logitech Dual Action not detected as input device in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, game-controller, logitech-gamepad

For some reason, my gamepad stopped working.  It's detected when I plug it into the USB port, but it's not recognized as an input device.

`dmesg`

```
[  917.280315] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  917.462991] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c216
[  917.462994] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  917.462995] usb 1-3: Product: Logitech Dual Action
[  917.462996] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
```

Notice it's not being added as an input device.

`lsusb`

```
...
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c216 Logitech, Inc. Dual Action Gamepad
...
```

... but it's recognized in the USB hub.

`ls /dev/input/by-path`

```
pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-mouse
pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-mouse
pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7:1.0-event
platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
platform-i8042-serio-4-event-mouse
platform-i8042-serio-4-mouse
```

... and it's not being added as an input device.

I have joydev and usbhid compiled into the kernel.  This gamepad used to work, but it seemed to randomly stop working and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Does the gamepad work with another OS? another computer?

Comment: Yes, it works under Windows 8 on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the driver that was responsible for my particular gamepad was moved over to CONFIG_HID_LOGITECH.  After enabling that in my kernel, the gamepad works again.